# Azure App Service Application Setting Value not Updating

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I am trying to load my appsettings.test.json file on a test API and I am having problems reading environment variables. Works fine locally but when I push it to the Azure App Service I keep getting pointed to my dev appsettings.json file.

I will attach my settings below and the API call results I used to verify this issue. Every other custom value works aside ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

#### Azure App Service Application Settings

[image]

#### App Service Endpoint for testing

```
[HttpGet("env")]
public IActionResult GetEnvVariable()
{
    var test = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
    var test1 = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT");
    return Ok($"ASPNETCORE: {test}\nDOTNET: {test1}");
}
```

#### App Service Endpoint response

[image]

#### Program.cs

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

#### Program.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //register bugsnag, swagger,  jwt auth, auto mapper, service classes, db context, controllers
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

                app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
                {
                    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test API V1");
                });
            }

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseMiddleware<GlobalErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
```

#### CSPROJ

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>$(MSBuildProjectName)</AssemblyName>
    <RootNamespace>$(MSBuildProjectName.Replace(" ", "_"))</RootNamespace>
    <Configurations>Release;Debug;Test</Configurations>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Test|AnyCPU' ">
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <IntermediateOutputPath>obj\Release\net6.0</IntermediateOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>True</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Development.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Production.json" />
    <Content Remove="appsettings.Test.json" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="appsettings.Development.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.Production.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="appsettings.Test.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Test.Api.Business\Test.Api.Business.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Additional Information
This app service is using the F1 free plan, could that be why?

Comment: Can you check or share your `Startup` code and see if the ASPNETCORE value has been overwritten?

Comment: Please share your `.csproj`, `Program.cs` and `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: @CharlesHan I have posted my startup.cs code, please have a look

Comment: @Harshitha I have added my .csproj, Program.cs and appsettings.json file, please have  a look

Comment: You have not set any values in `appsettings.json`.What does your `appsettings.test.json` have? Are you referring Azure application settings as `appsettings.test.json`?

Comment: I did not want to put credentials here, that is all my `appsettings.json` consists of. That being said, the issue here is that ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT is set to Development and not Test even though I have it as that in applications settings. Because of that the wrong `appsettings.json` is being used @Harshitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, if anyone encounters this issue. My project was originally a .NET CORE 3.1 project, even after upgrading to 6 there were obviously still lingering files which wouldn't be cleared just because I targeted a newer framework.

The culprit was my `web.config` file, it was overriding my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` env variable.

```
<environmentVariables>
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT" value="44364" />
<environmentVariable name="COMPLUS_ForceENC" value="1" />
</environmentVariables>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Azure NuGet packages (`Azure.ResourceManager.Resources`, `Azure.ResourceManager.AppService`) to update an App Setting, you can do something like this:

```cs
// Retrieve the AppService resource
WebSiteResource myWebApp = await appServiceCollection.GetAsync(appServiceName, cancellationToken);

// Then, get its settings
var myWebAppSettings = (await meshAppWebApp.GetApplicationSettingsAsync(cancellationToken)).Value;

// Finally, update a variable
myWebAppSettings.Properties["MY_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

// Invoke the update method, to apply the changes.
await myWebApp.UpdateApplicationSettingsAsync(myWebAppSettings, cancellationToken);
```